# sql select with column name like

Tags: sql

I have a table with column names `a1,a2...,b1.b2...`.

How can I select all those with column names like `a%`?

Comment: you are trying to query for a list of column names, and thn query those columns?

Comment: Though it's possible I would strongly advise you against doing this. Your question implies one of two things 1) That you don't want to explicitly declare all your columns (which you should) or 2) That you don't know the schema of the table you're querying. If you don't know the schema of the table you will not have consistent dimensionality of the dataset returned....

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for your comment. I will ask a related newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot with standard SQL.  Column names are not treated like data in SQL.

If you use a SQL engine that has, say, meta-data tables storing column names, types, etc. you may select on that table instead.

Comment: .. which is standard sql, is what I meant to say.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, you're correct information_schema is standard SQL.  However, not all engines implement it, and not all use this name.  Really depends on the engine.

Answer (score 87):

This will get you the list

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='table1' and column_name like 'a%'
```

If you want to use that to construct a query, you could do something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select '
select @sql = @sql + '[' + column_name +'],'
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='table1' and column_name like 'a%'
set @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql)-1) -- remove trailing comma
set @sql = @sql + ' from table1'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Note that the above is written for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard, I like how you also included a query to use the actual columns dynamically. I'm in a situation where the columns grow on the table outside of my control, so this works perfectly for me. Voted up!

Comment: This is so awesome! Will definitely be using this.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

```
select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = my_table_name AND COLUMN_NAME like 'a%'
```

TO inline rows you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) and for execution [EXEC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) function.

Answer (score 6):

This will show you the table name and column name

```
select table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%breakfast%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM SysColumns WHERE Name like 'a%'
```

Will get you a list of columns, you will want to filter more to restrict it to your target table

From there you can construct some ad-hoc sql

Comment: thanks.It would be nice if some db can treat columns in a symmetric way as rows,like a speead sheet in excel...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice way to display the information that you want:

```
SELECT B.table_catalog as 'Database_Name',
         B.table_name as 'Table_Name',
        stuff((select ', ' + A.column_name
              from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
              where A.Table_name = B.Table_Name
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
              , 1, 2, '') as 'Columns'
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B
  WHERE B.TABLE_NAME like '%%'
        AND B.COLUMN_NAME like '%%'
  GROUP BY B.Table_Catalog, B.Table_Name
  Order by 1 asc
```

Add anything between either '%%' in the main select to narrow down what tables and/or column names you want.

Answer (score 1):

Blorgbeard had a great answer for SQL server. If you have a MySQL server like mine then the following will allow you to select the information from columns where the name is like some key phrase. You just have to substitute the table name, database name, and keyword.

```
SET @columnnames = (SELECT concat("`",GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR "`, `"),"`") 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_database' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE "%keyword%");

SET @burrito = CONCAT("SELECT ",@columnnames," FROM your_table");

PREPARE result FROM @burrito;
EXECUTE result;
```

Comment: In my case, the column names exceeded 1024 characters, so I had to insert the following line at the top: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` [source](https://www.namasteui.com/mysql-group_concat-maximum-length/)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Blorgbeard for the genious idea.

By the way Blorgbeard's query was not working for me so I edited it:

```
DECLARE @Table_Name as VARCHAR(50) SET @Table_Name = 'MyTable'          -- put here you table name
DECLARE @Column_Like as VARCHAR(20) SET @Column_Like = '%something%'    -- put here you element
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @sql = 'select '

SELECT @sql = @sql + '[' + sys.columns.name + '],'
FROM sys.columns 
JOIN sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE sys.columns.name like @Column_Like
and sys.tables.name = @Table_Name

SET @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql)-1) -- remove trailing comma
SET @sql = @sql + ' from ' + @Table_Name

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using `SELECT * ILIKE` which is Snowflake SQL language extension.

> [SELECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select)
>
> **ILIKE 'pattern'**
>
> Specifies that only the columns that match pattern should be included in the results.
>
> In pattern, you can use the following SQL wildcards:
>
> - Use an underscore (_) to match any single character.
> - Use a percent sign (%) to match any sequence of zero or more characters.
>
> To match a sequence anywhere within the column name, begin and end the pattern with %.
>
> Matching is case-insensitive.

---

Using table structure from the question:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(a1 INT, a2 INT, a3 INT, b1 TEXT, b2 TEXT, b3 TEXT);

INSERT INTO tab(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3)
VALUES (1,2,3,'a','b','c');
```

Query:

```
SELECT * ILIKE 'a%'
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]