# Select multiple like named fields with expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have like fields like:

- Home Zip
- Business Zip
- Mailing Zip

How could I do something like this (match any field that has Zip):

```
SELECT ILIKE "%Zip"
FROM db_tbl
WHERE condition = 'foo'
```

Comment: Here is a good answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274594/sql-select-with-column-name-like

Comment: Thanks, post it as the answer and I will accept, as it leads to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good answer to your question:

stackoverflow.com/questions/5274594/

To summarize, standard SQL doesn't quite support that functionality, but you can get it somewhat working with a little work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can chain multiple LIKE statements with an OR, but SQL deals with data and not metadata, so there is no shortcut to 'search any field with X string for blah' anywhere in the SQL specification (or any SQL derivative I have ever used).