# Mysql sum all columns starting with some letters

Tags: mysql

I am trying add one column in my Mysql database that sums all the columns starting by 'tokenvalid' which can take the value of 1 or 0.

And let's say I have 50 columns like that in my database (i.e. tokenvalid1, tokenvalid2 ...., tokenvalide50) with other columns between.

Please find below the code I would like to implement. I know that is not correct at all but it is just to give you an idea of what I am trying to do. 
Thank you for your help!

```
'SELECT *, sum(column_name LIKE "tokenvalid"%) as total FROM points WHERE 1'
```

Comment: A schema like that violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), so that's probably the source of your problems here. You can't sum random column names, you generally pick one and one only per `SUM()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This post should help you. The post describes how to get the columns and then query for results.

[MySQL Like statement in SELECT column_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274594/sql-select-with-column-name-like)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you.

```
SET @colname = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`column_name`) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='points' AND `column_name` LIKE 'tokenvalid%');
SET @table = 'points';
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(',@colname,') FROM ', @table);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283562/2397717) answer by [RocketDonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009277/rocketdonkey)

Answer (score 0):

If the string is in your external application (like PHP), sure, just construct the MySQL statement.

If the string is inside a MySQL table, you can't. MySQL has no eval() or such function. The following is impossible:

Suppose you have a table 'queries' with a field "columnname" that refers to one of the column names in the table "mytable". There might be additional columns in 'queries' that allow you to select the columnname you want...

```
INSERT INTO queries  (columname) VALUES ("name")
SELECT (select columnname from queries) from mytable
```

You can however work with [PREPARED STATEMENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Be aware this is very hacky.

```
SELECT columnname from queries into @colname;
SET @table = 'mytable';
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ',@colname,' FROM ', @table);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```